# MVC: Cannot refactor my HtmlHelper to use a client side script function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom HtmlHelper;

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, Leave _leave)
{
    string url = string.Format("/Payroll/Delete?_employeeOtherLeaveId={0}", _leave.LeaveId.ToString());
    return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Default",
        new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = _leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
        //new { @class = "delete-link" }
        new { onclick = "$.ajax({url: this.href, type: 'DELETE', success: function(result) {$('#wholepage').html(result);}}); return false;" }
}
```

As you can see I have a long string for my onclick event for my RouteLink command.
I want to put this in some unobtrusive Javascript, and then put in some extra javascript for a confirmation popup. 
So if I comment out the onclick event and uncomment out the class, I intend to use instead the following Javascript function

```
$('#delete-link').click(function () {
    var flag = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?');
    if (flag == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function (result) {
                // update some DOM element with the result returned by the
                // server. So supposing that you have some <div id="someContainer">
                // that will contain the part of the DOM you want updated:
                $('#wholepage').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem then is that a get the error;
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Delete' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.PayrollController'

But this is a public method, so why should I get that?

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int _employeeOtherLeaveId)
    {
        EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(_employeeOtherLeaveId);
        return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
    }
```

---

Some people have pointed out that this.url will have the wrong value. This appears to be the case, Firebug it reports that this.href is undefined.
So I change the helper method as below;

```
  public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, Leave _leave)
    {
        string url = string.Format("/Payroll/Delete?_employeeOtherLeaveId={0}", _leave.LeaveId.ToString());
        return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Default",
            new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = _leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
            new { onclick = "DeleteRow('" + url + "')" }
     }
```

The javascript function looks like this;

```
function DeleteRow(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#wholepage').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `this.href` in your click function?

Comment: you are generating a delete url in the helper but using "url: this.href", for ajax submit, is this correct/bug?

Comment: This may well be a bug. When I looked in Firebug this.href was not defined. But when I sent the url as a parameter to the function and used that instead, I got the same response.

Comment: I have edited my question to demonstrate this.

Comment: Does Firebug report a DELETE request sent to the correct URL? If not, you can narrow it down to a problem still hiding somewhere in the Ajax code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that jQuery does not support making Delete calls via Ajax so it is doing a GET or a POST which is not found on the controller because you are restricting to delete.

See here on how to solve this issue:

http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/9132_put-and-delete-with-jquery

Hope this helps

Addition:

I have looked into this more and the latest jQuery may support it but states:

> type String Default: 'GET' The type of
>   request to make ("POST" or "GET"),
>   default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP
>   request methods, such as PUT and
>   DELETE, can also be used here, but
>   they are not supported by all
>   browsers.

The way that MVC gest around flakey browser support is to add a hidden field to forms that delete called _method and give it a value of delete

So you may wish to add to your ajax code:

```
$('#delete-link').click(function () {
    var flag = confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?');
    if (flag == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            data: {_method: "delete"},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                // update some DOM element with the result returned by the
                // server. So supposing that you have some <div id="someContainer">
                // that will contain the part of the DOM you want updated:
                $('#wholepage').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I earlier wrote that this worked. I got mixed up with my code I am afraid. Now I find this doesn't work. I get the same error. Incidently I get the same error when I click cancel in the confirm messagebox. Why would that be?

Comment: You will probably want to add  event.preventDefault(); on the click event as the link is an href and returning false is not always enough to stop the browser

Comment: My original comment still stands though I think you are not hitting the DELETE action as you are restricting to delete, try removing the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)] to test this

Comment: The only way I could get it to work was to replace DELETE with POST.